# Is it MongoDB suitable for authentication and sensitive operations?

Tags: php, security, mongodb, authentication

I want to create a web based chat system with authentication.
It may hold sensitive data like emails, passwords and etc...

The records on my database maybe become grater and grater at each second.
Is MongoDB suitable for this plan and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the standard security precautions that you should take with any application requiring authentication and other sensitive operations, you will be fine. MongoDB does not present any known significant security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that default MongoDB configuration is "no authentication" so anyone can connect to the DB. So either you should limit network access or better yet, enable authentication. Also, there is no support for encrypting traffic on the wire, so you will need to use something like ipsec/SSH tunnel etc if you want encryption on the wire.

Important consideration specific to MongoDB: 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Do+I+Have+to+Worry+About+SQL+Injection